# "git mv *" returns "bad source" in Powershell

Tags: git, powershell, cmd.exe, msys

When inside a git repository in Powershell or CMD, issuing

`git mv * whatever`

will return

> fatal: bad source, source=*, destination=whatever

This works fine when using MSYS (Git Bash).

Comment: CMD and PowerShell does not expand globing characters, like bash does.

Comment: @PetSerAl you should post this as the answer along with suggesting to use the bash shell; totally solves the problem! Thanks :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As has been pointed out by others in this thread, the star does not automatically expand to file names in PowerShell. Thus, the command let `get-childItem` needs to be used, which explicitely tells PowerShell to expand wildcard characters.

You want to put the result of `get-childItem *` into parentheses so that they are expanded before the entire `git mv` command is executed:

```
git mv (get-childItem *) whatever
```

To save a few key strokes, you might want to use the alias `gci` for `get-childItem`:

```
git mv (gci *) whatever
```

Comment: This is so clean, and ought to be the accepted answer.

Comment: Use `-k` flag to skip commands that produce errors. For example, if you're copying items to a subdirectory that already exists, you'll get `can not move directory into itself`.

Answer (score 5):

As @PetSerAI said, the Windows command prompt and PowerShell will not expand the globing characters and it makes `git mv` fail.

Use a bash shell like MSYS instead.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how does Powershell interpret globbing characters?

Comment: I'm not really sure, sorry :( I think it has to do with how PS works - in that it pipes objects. e.g. https://gist.github.com/DNNX/1481234

Comment: While I agree that PowerShell does not handle this particularly well, on Windows many people live in PowerShell, and just saying "use a bash shell" to a PowerShell user is like telling a vim user to "use emacs instead." [This answer below](https://superuser.com/a/1591487/413591) does provide a halfway-decent workaround in PowerShell.

Comment: @RussFrizzell-Carlton "many people" don't have git installed. It comes with bash shell by default on Windows.

Comment: and why would we use what looks like bloatware (i installed git, not bash) when we have two perfectly good shells already?

Comment: Also the problem is not with cmd or ps, they have been capable of wildcarding file match for like, ever.  `dir *.txt` for example. Git just assumes its working in a *nix shell.

Comment: This is factually correct but not a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Using PowerShell to move the content of `source` to `whatever` folder you can run this command:

```sh
Get-ChildItem .\source\ | ForEach-Object { git mv $_.FullName .\whatever\ }
```

Your directory structure would look like this before:

```
+--C:\code\Project\
|
+----+bootstrap.py
+----+requirements.txt
+----+.gitignore
+----+source
|
+---------+manage.py
+---------+modules
+---------+templates
+---------+static
+----+whatever
|
+---------+cool.py
```

And after running would look like this:

```
+--C:\code\Project\
|
+----+bootstrap.py
+----+requirements.txt
+----+.gitignore
+----+source
+----+whatever
|
+---------+cool.py
+---------+manage.py
+---------+modules
+---------+templates
+---------+static
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution for cmd

```
for %i in (*) do git mv %i whatever/
```

Answer (score -1):

This also happens when you "source" directory doesn't exist.